# 'float' object can't be interpreted as int, but converting to int yields no output

Tags: python, for-loop, int

So I'm trying to test if something is a palindrome. Here is my code:

This function returns a string of the first half of a larger string. ("TEST" returns "TE", "HELLO" returns "HE")

```
def takeStart(s):
    start = ""

    # The following determines the final index of the first half

    if len(s)%2==0:  
        a = (len(s)/2)-1
    else:
        a = ((len(s)-1)/2)-1

    for i in range(a):
        start+=s[i]
    return start
```

This function returns a string of the second half of a larger string. ("TEST" returns "ST", "HELLO" returns "LO")

```
def takeEnd(s):  
    end = ""

    # The following determines the beginning index of the second half

    if len(s)%2==0:
        a = (len(s)/2)
    else:
        a = ((len(s)-1)/2)

    for i in range(a,len(s)):
        end+=s[i]
    return end
```

This function flips a string. ("TEST" returns "TSET", "HELLO" returns "OLLEH")

```
def flip(s):
    flipped = ""
    for i in range(1,len(s)):
        flipped+=s[len(s)-i]
    flipped+=s[0]
    return flipped
```

This code takes every product of two 3-digit numbers, and checks if it's a palindrome

```
for i in range(100,1000):
    for q in range(100,1000):
        a = i*q
        if takeStart(str(a)) == flip(takeEnd(str(a))):
            print(str(a))
```

When this code is run, it outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[redacted]", line 39, in <module>
    if takeStart(str(a)) == flip(takeEnd(str(a))):
  File "[redacted]", line 14, in takeStart
    for i in range(a):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Alright, I thought I just convert a to an integer and all should be swell.

Doing that appears to remove all errors, but there is NO output whatsoever. (There are new lines every once and a while which makes me think it's working but not outputing any data)

Any ideas on why this is happening?

UPDATE: my code now:

```
def takeStart(s):
    start = ""
    if len(s)%2==0:
        a = (len(s)//2)
    else:
        a = (len(s)-1)//2
    return start[0:a]

def takeEnd(s):  
    end = ""
    if len(s)%2==0:
        a = (len(s)//2)
    else:
        a = ((len(s)-1)//2)

    return end[int(a):len(s)]

def flip(s):
    return s[::-1]

for i in range(100,1000):
    for q in range(100,1000):
        a = i*q
        if takeStart(str(a)) == flip(takeEnd(str(a))):
            print(str(a))
```

This is just outputting every single number.
I tested each method and they're returning empty strings. (I'm assuming), which is why every number is passing the palindrome check and printing.

Comment: are you running with python 2 or python 3?

Comment: As a side note, you're making this a lot harder than it needs to be. For example, instead of looping over the indices one by one, just use a slice.

Comment: Looks like you're using Python 3 where the `a` ends up a `float` as a result of the division operations... You can force integer division using `//` instead, but I haven't thought too much if that's what you want to do... as @abarnet mentions - there are much simpler ways of doing this (looks like a Euler challenge...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, using `range(int(a))` and `range(int(a), len(s))` will solve your error. As Jon Clements points out, you can solve that more easily by just using `//` instead of `/` to get integers in the first place. But either way, it's not causing any problems.

Your problem is that `range`s, and just about everything related in Python, are half-open. So, your `takeStart` function is returning all the values up to, but not including, the half-way point—that is, it gives you `H` for `HELLO`, `T` for `TEST`, `BIGG` for `BIGGERTEST`.

Just get rid of the `-1` on your `a = …` lines, and that will solve that problem.

And then it prints out a whole bunch of output lines, all palindromes, which I assume is what you were intending to do.

However, you're still not going to get any odd-length palindromes. For example, with 'MADAM', even when you get the functions right, `takeStart(s)` is `MA`, `takeEnd(s)` is `DAM`, `flip(takeEnd(s))` is `MAD`, and that's not the same as `MAD`. Even though your functions are working right, they're not solving the problem. So there's a bug in your design as well as your implementation. If you think about it for a while, you should figure out how to make this work.

And, once you do, you should realize that `takeStart` and `takeEnd` can be simplified a lot. (Hint: In which cases do you really need to treat odd and even lengths differently?)

---

While we're at it, this:

```
foo = ""
for i in range(x, y):
    foo += s[i]
return foo
```

… is just a verbose, slow, and easy-to-get-wrong way of writing this:

```
return foo[x:y]
```

And, likewise, your whole `flipped` function is just:

```
return s[::-1]
```

Comment: Since you're making good points (as normal). I would also throw out (related to your existing points I've just noticed) the OP should really probably consider more a "find_middle", and have take_start and take_end use that slightly...

Comment: Awesome. My only problem now is an out of bounds exception when adding the characters to `flipped` in the function `flip`. Is there a way you can do the [x:y] thing to go backwards?

Comment: @JonClements: Agreed… although it's easier to figure out how to simplify things if he works around the `HEL`/`LLO` problem _before_ writing `take_middle`…

Comment: @CortneyReagle: Yes, completely-specified slices look like `[start:end:step]`. The defaults are (effectively) `0`, `len(s)`, and `1`, but you can specify anything you want, including negative numbers.

Comment: @abarnert I already had a take_middle function, but just as you said, I separated it to make it easier for myself to work things out

Comment: @CortneyReagle: You should be able to reduce all of these functions to one line, once you know about slicing and think about the hint I explained. Then, figuring out how to make them even simpler by just calculating the middle once takes another trick… but it might be simple enough even without that one.

Comment: @albarnert hmm, I did everything you said but now the takeEnd and takeStart functions are outputting just empty. Do I need to do something to the splices to make sure it's reading from string `s`?

Comment: @CortneyReagle: What does your code look like now? It's hard to debug it if I can't see it, but my guess would be that you're calculating something but never `return`ing it…

Comment: @CortneyReagle: Also, it will help you a lot in trying to debug your code if you test the functions directly: `print(takeStart('HELLO'), takeEnd('HELLO'), takeStart('TEST'), takeEnd('TEST'))` instead of running the whole loop and trying to guess what went wrong. Unless you're getting `HE LO TE ST` or `HEL LLO TE ST`, it's not going to work, and it'll be a lot easier to fix `HE LLO TE ST` than to figure out why you're only getting 41% as many numbers as you should…

Comment: @CortneyReagle: In the new version, you're returning `start[0:a]`, not `s[0:a]`. Since `start` is an empty string, `start[0:a]` is also an empty string.

Comment: @CortneyReagle Congrats. Just to note a slight trick that can be used to compute an index that's convenient for an end slice, and a negative start slice, is `sum(divmod(len(string), 2))` Which gives you `3` for a length of `5` or `2` for a length of 4... So, `'ABCBA'[:3]` gives you `ABC` and `'ABCBA'[-3:]` gives you CBA... Then check one is the flip of the other and you're done...

Answer (score 0):

> Pythons `range()` function does not support floats but numpys `arange()`
>   function does

To use `arange()` function, you need to install and import the `numpy` package. 
We’ll here use the `arange()` function for generating a range of float numbers.
The `arange()` has the same signature as the built-in `range()` method. But we can pass float type arguments as parameters to this function.

```
import numpy
arange (start, stop, step)
```

In a full code example this looks as follows:

```
from numpy import arange

print("Float range using NumPy arange():")

print("\nTest 1:")
for i in arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1):
    print(i, end=', ')
```